# Triggering Kusto commands using 'ADX Command' activity in ADFv2 vs calling WebAPI on it

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

In ADFv2 (Azure Data Factory V2) if we need to trigger a command on an ADX (Azure Data Explorer) cluster , we have two choices:-

1. Use 'Azure Data Explorer Commmand' activity
2. Use POST method provided in the 'WebActivity'  activity

Having figured out that both the methods work I would say from development/maintenance point of view the first method sounds more slick and systematic especially because it is out of the box feature to support Kusto in ADFv2. Is there any scenario where the Web Activity method would be more preferable or more performant? I am trying to figure out if it's alright to simply use the ADX Command activity all the time to run any Kusto command from ADFv2 instead of ever using the Web activity,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed recommended to use the "Azure Data Explorer Command" activity:

1. That activity is more comfortable, as you don't have to construct by yourself a the HTTP request.
2. That command takes care of few things for you, such as:

   - In case you are running an async command, it will poll the Operations table until your async command is completed.
   - Logging.
   - Error handling.
3. In addition, you should take into consideration that the result format will be different between both cases, and that each activity has its own limits in terms of response size and timeout.